# Cocoapods installation on windows 8

Tags: windows, cocoapods, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm new to mobile apps and to phonegap.
But in the tutorials, they ask you to install cocoapods using a command function:

> $ sudo gem install cocoapods

but this is a linux command and not a window one.
and i can't find a way to install it on window.
Can anyone guide me please to the right track.
thanks

Answer (score 7):

You just need to install ruby, which you can download from here: https://rubyinstaller.org/

Then you can use `gem` to run ruby-cli command, therefore you can run `gem install cocoapods`, you don't need `sudo`, that is only to run it as administrator in linux, but on windows you can just run the cmd as administrator, from the right click menu.

Comment: Any `pod *` command returns this error: **[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)**